# Hierarchical models - empty groups and missing groups

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, multilevel-analysis

In hierarchical models (HLMs, Hierarchical Bayesian models, etc.) parameters are estimated for each group:

```
|                   population                    |
|----------------+----------------+---------------|
|     group 1    |     group 2    |    group 3    |
|----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+----+-----+----|
| x1 |  x2 |  x3 | x4 |  x5 |  x6 | x7 |  x8 | x9 |
```

Best practice says I should split my data to in-sample (for training) and out-of-sample (for testing) data.

What if my in-sample data contains no samples for group 3? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Stratifying makes sense in this situation. Essentially split up each group into a training and test set and then combine them to get your overall test/training split. This way you retain the class distribution, which makes sense assuming the sample is similar to any future data/the population as a whole, which presumably it is.